# Пропуски некоторых значений в train датасете

Tags: машинное-обучение, kaggle

Подскажите пожалуйста, решил порешать задачу на kaggle, где по данным о каждом пассажире нужно предсказать, кто будет спасен, применяя методы машинного обучения.
Значение возраста некоторых пассажиров неизвестно, но для нас возраст играет большое значение и является хорошим признаком, так как в первую очередь спасают женщин и детей.
**Как обычно поступают с такими данным, значение некоторых полей в которых неизвестно? На ум приходит просто удалить такие строки данных. Но, возможно, есть практики более корректного обращения с такими строками данных?** Ведь иногда не известно какой из признаков будет играть важное значение и если удалить все строки с пропущенными полями датасет сильно сокраится и наверное, точность уменьшится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный вопрос трудно дать однозначный ответ. Очень многое зависит от конкретных данных. Возможно придется перепробовать несколько различных вариантов.

Кроме уже упомянутого вами удаления строк с неполными данными, можно попробовать заполнить недостающие данные значениями - например:

- заполнить средним значением
- заполнить средним для какой-нибудь группы (например: сгруппировать по полу, классу каюты, etc. и заполнить средним значением для данной группы)
- заполнить наиболее часто встречающимся значением (глобально или для группы)

В любом случае лучше протестировать разные подходы на тестовом сете.

PS в `SciKit-Learn` есть класс для заполнения пропущенных данных - [sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html)